# Can you please help with my hector mapping launch file?

Tags: navigation, mapping, roslaunch, hector-mapping, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a LaserScan node "keyencelaser" that is publishing on the topic "scan" with frame "laser_frame"

```
  ros::init(argc, argv, "keyencelaser_publisher");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Publisher scan_pub = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>("scan", 50);
  (...)
  scan.header.frame_id = "laser_frame";
```

My launch file currently looks like:

```
<launch>


<node pkg="keyencelaser" type="keyencelaser_rosnode" name="keyencelaser" />
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_to_base_link" args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0 0 0.0 /odom /base_link 100"/>
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser_link" args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0 0 0.0 /base_link /laser_frame 100"/>
<param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="false"/>
<param name="map_frame" value="map" />
<param name="base_frame" value="base_link" />
<param name="odom_frame" value="base_link" />
<node pkg="hector_mapping" type="hector_mapping" name="hector_mapping" output="screen">
  <param name="use_tf_scan_transformation" value="true" />
  <param name="use_tf_pose_start_estimate" value="false" />
  <param name="map_resolution" value="0.050" />
  <param name="map_size" value="2048" />
  <param name="scan_subscriber_queue_size" value="5" />
  <param name="scan_topic" value="scan" />
  <param name="tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name" value="scanmatcher_frame" />
</node>
</launch>
```

But I throw this error once I use my launch file:

```
[ INFO] [1482419456.331809455]: lookupTransform base_link to laser_frame timed out. Could not transform laser scan into base_frame.
Check failed in file /usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_expression.hpp at line 2007:
size1 == size2
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::numeric::ublas::bad_argument'
  what():  bad argument
```

Can someone please help me figure this out? I have tried multiple combinations but can't quite get it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250617/can-you-please-help-with-my-hector-mapping-launch-file?/) by [ateator](https://answers.ros.org/users/27086/ateator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2016-12-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ateator](https://answers.ros.org/users/27086/ateator/) on 2016-12-22**:
BTW I can successfully view my LaserScan on rviz. If you'd like me to post any information, please just ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If pub_map_odom_transform = false , you must close 'statci_transform_publiser' to publish odom->base_link

If pub_map_odom_transform = true , set odom_frame = odom and publish odom->base_link tf

---

Originally posted by [jinn](https://answers.ros.org/users/28820/jinn/) with karma: 16 on 2017-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0